# Android: using predefined dimens parameters in programmatic layout

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

I want to use some predefined dimensions from my dimens.xml file in my programmatic layout.

So for instance, in my dimens.xml file I have:

```
<dimen name="margin1">40dip</dimen>
<dimen name="margin2">40dip</dimen>
```

And then in my programmatic textview I have:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpMargin = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( R.dimen.margin1, R.dimen.margin2);
```

Applying the layout parameter to my textview results in an enormous view.

I already found the problem. If I print out:

```
Log.e("Metrics", "margin width = " +  String.valueOf(R.dimen.margin1));
```

...it gives an enormous value: `margin width = 2131034112`. The thing that's messing it up is the units, "dip".

So my question is: what's the correct way to specify dimensions without units for calling programmatically? If that's not possible, can I alter R.dimen.margin1 so I can use it as a programmatic layout parameter?

EDIT: It wasn't the units messing it up -- it's returning the internal ID! (As *ianhanniballake* says below, I needed to call with `getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.margin1)`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use

```
getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.margin1)
```

or

```
getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin1)
```

Your code is returning the internal ID assigned to 'R.dimen.margin1' rather than the value you assigned in your XML file.